# NSMutableArray last Object

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, icarousel

I'm trying the iCarousel, there is a function that deletes the view's index and the array's index,

```
NSInteger index = carousel.currentItemIndex;
[carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
[imagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

I'm deleting it until one item remains, then if one item remains I want to insert the duplicate of it. I tried this:

`insertItemAtindex:carousel.currentItemIndex` but it's inserting the last View.

But what I wanted is to insert carousel's/imagesArray last object/index in my view. How can I implement it, or how can I determine an NSMutableArray's last object that is left in the view?

Answer (score 9):

`carousel.lastObject` !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can check for last object using -

```
int count = [yourArray count];
[yourArray objectAtIndex:count - 1]; //this will always return you last object
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a little?

Comment: Just do this: `lastObject = [yourArray objectAtIndex: ([yourArray count]-1)]`

Comment: I know. I was just telling Kobe.04 how to use your code. All credit goes to you. That's why I upvoted your answer.